# Makefile command substitution problem

Tags: linux, makefile

[rebar](http://github.com/basho/rebar) doesn't automatically rebuild files when given a different configuration file. So, I've tried to do it on the Makefile level:

```
REBAR=./rebar
REBAR_DEBUG=$(REBAR) -C rebar.debug.config
REBAR_COMPILE=$(REBAR) get-deps compile
LAST_CONFIG:=$(cat config.tmp)
PLT=dialyzer/sqlite3.plt

all: config_normal compile

compile:
    $(REBAR_COMPILE)

test:
    $(REBAR_COMPILE) eunit

clean:
    -rm -rf deps ebin priv doc/* .eunit c_src/*.o

docs:
    $(REBAR_COMPILE) doc

static: config_debug
    $(REBAR_DEBUG) get-deps compile
ifeq ($(wildcard $(PLT)),)
    dialyzer --build_plt --apps kernel stdlib erts --output_plt $(PLT) 
else
    dialyzer --plt $(PLT) -r ebin
endif

cross_compile: config_cross
    $(REBAR_COMPILE) -C rebar.cross_compile.config

valgrind: clean
    $(REBAR_DEBUG) get-deps compile
    valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --num-callers=20 ./test.sh

ifeq ($(LAST_CONFIG),normal)
config_normal:
    echo "$(LAST_CONFIG) == normal"
else
config_normal: clean
    echo "$(LAST_CONFIG) != normal"
    rm -f config.tmp
    echo "normal" > config.tmp
endif

ifeq ($(LAST_CONFIG),debug)
config_debug: ;
else
config_debug: clean
    rm -f config.tmp
    echo "debug" > config.tmp
endif

ifeq ($(LAST_CONFIG),cross)
config_cross: ;
else
config_cross: clean
    rm -f config.tmp
    echo "cross" > config.tmp
endif

.PHONY: all compile test clean docs static valgrind config_normal config_debug config_cross
```

The intention is hopefully obvious: when I use a target which needs a certain config file, check if the same file was used last time; run `clean` and record the configuration we are using now.

But it doesn't work, and the files get recompiled constantly:

```
aromanov@alexey-desktop:~/workspace/gmcontroller/lib/sqlite3$ make
rm -rf deps ebin priv doc/* .eunit c_src/*.o
echo " != normal"
 != normal
rm -f config.tmp
echo "normal" > config.tmp
./rebar get-deps compile
==> sqlite3 (get-deps)
==> sqlite3 (compile)
Compiled src/sqlite3_lib.erl
Compiled src/sqlite3.erl
Compiling c_src/sqlite3_drv.c
```

Despite config.tmp containing "normal":

```
aromanov@alexey-desktop:~/workspace/gmcontroller/lib/sqlite3$ LAST_CONFIG=$(cat config.tmp); echo $LAST_CONFIG
normal
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this part actually work correctly "ifeq ($(LAST_CONFIG),normal)"?

Comment: Possibly not, but that's why I added `echo "$(LAST_CONFIG) != normal"`, and it seems to show that `$(LAST_CONFIG)` is empty.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're missing the part where you need to use [`shell`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html#Shell-Function) in order to actually call external programs when defining a variable.

```
LAST_CONFIG:=$(shell cat config.tmp)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the *shell assignment operator*

```
LAST_CONFIG != cat config.tmp
```

[§ How make Reads a Makefile](http://gnu.org/software/make/manual/make#Reading-Makefiles)

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/suede/blob/e5d6264/Makefile#L2-L3)