# Why might a variable be empty in a Makefile but not the terminal?

Tags: bash, makefile

In a Makefile, I have a recipe like the following:

```
date:
    echo $(date +"%m-%d-%Y %T")
```

When I execute this recipe/makefile in my terminal, echo only prints an empty line. However, if I execute the echo command directly in my terminal, it prints something like "01-22-2021 12:34:49". Why isn't my makefile working and what can I do to fix it? My best guess is it may have something to do with how each line in a makefile gets executed in a separate shell, but that seems like a weak guess and I have no idea what to do about it or what I can try... please help.

Note: I am aware that there are alternative ways to get the correct output (i.e. something like what my terminal printed). For example, I have found that using the code below in my makefile achieves what I need in my particular situation. Feel free to share alternative approaches to getting such results, but the core issue I am trying to raise is why the makefile fails, so please address that if you can.

```
date:
    date +"%m-%d-%Y %T" >> fake.log
```

Comment: This might help: [Makefile command substitution problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678967/makefile-command-substitution-problem)

Comment: While you could use `$(shell` as described in the above link, I don't think it's the proper solution for what the OP was trying to do -- please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26564874/8710344) for an explanation of double dollar signs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
date:
    echo $(shell date +"%m-%d-%Y %T")
```

Make doesn't know what you are trying to do

Comment: I suggest to insert a tab before `echo`.

Comment: Using `$(shell` will cause make to run the command at parse time as opposed to when the shell command is actually run.  You should do `echo $$(date +"%m-%d-%Y %T")`, which will cause make to run `echo $(date +"%m-%d-%Y %T")` down to the shell, and date get expanded when the shell runs this command.