# assigning jq result to makefile variable

Tags: bash, makefile, jq

I have the following command as a makefile command:

```
update-env:
    echo "{ \"Variables\":${ENV_VALUE}}" > ./new_env.json && \
    UPDATE_ENVVARS=$$(jq -s '.[0] as $$a |.[1] as $$b | $$a * $$b' old_env.json new_env.json | jq -c . ) && \
    echo "${UPDATE_ENVVARS}"
```

1. the `${ENV_VALUE}` is taken when

```
make update-env ENV_VALUE="{\\\"HOST_URL\\\": \\\"https:\\\/\\\/test.com\\\"}"
```

2. the file `new_env.json` is generated properly
3. when executing `jq -s '.[0] as $a |.[1] as $b | $a * $b' old_env.json new_env.json | jq -c .`  it generates the appropriate compact json result desired.

When running everything in sequence (the assignment and echo for validation), I get an empty result.

My goal for the command is to merge two json output and assign it to the `UPDATE_ENVVARS` for it to be reused as an input for another command that will accept the json. Per testing, it came out empty when echo, when I execute the `jq` solo, the merge output is functional.

Comment: Typo: `"${UPDATE_ENVVARS}"` --> `"$${UPDATE_ENVVARS}"`?  If that's not the fix you're looking for then I think you'll need to provide a lot more context/information.

Comment: If that's in a recipe, it's not setting a makefile variable, it's setting a shell variable.

Comment: @G.M. adding double `$$` does not yield any output.

Comment: @Barmar have added more context to what I am looking for

Comment: Please show _an actual Makefile_ complete enough to be run that demonstrates what you're trying to accomplish. There are some possible problems that the snippet here simply isn't complete enough to demonstrate.

Comment: (for example, if you're correctly setting the variable in one subshell but then trying to access it in another... well, really, that's the most likely problem there is -- you should be using backslash-continuation to put both the assignment and the use in the same shell, _or_ the assignment should be moved outside of a target)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4679166/14122 demonstrating the proper practice if you want an assignment available in multiple targets, though the edit makes it clear that's overkill for your current needs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy updated to show the makefile target command and 1 more line to show the sequence desired

Comment: (that said, your current code isn't valid JSON syntax without an `ENV_VALUE` preassigned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a minor bit of editing was needed:

```
update-env:
    echo '{ "Variables":${ENV_VALUE}}' > ./new_env.json && \
    UPDATE_ENVVARS=$$(jq -s '.[0] as $$a |.[1] as $$b | $$a * $$b' old_env.json new_env.json | jq -c . ) && \
    echo "$${UPDATE_ENVVARS}"
```

Note:

- We're using single quotes in the first-line `echo` -- the substitution is performed by `make`, not by the shell, so single quotes don't suppress it.
- We're doubling up the `$$` in the last line, so we're expanding the shell variable set in the second line of the recipe, not a make variable that nothing ever set at all.

See this working at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/RoyalIdolizedProfile

By contrast, if you want to assign to a *make* variable instead of a *shell* variable, this question is duplicative of [Makefile command substitution problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678967/makefile-command-substitution-problem/4679166#4679166), and the [answer by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4679166/14122) is appropriate.

Comment: your correction is what I needed. I also had to correct my escaped `ENV_VALUE` entry also (the param was entered as double quote) - thanks!